# How to specify the number of rows in a Grid in Expression Blend?

Tags: windows-phone-7, grid, expression-blend

My WP7 layout didn't look right until I specified the correct number of RowDefinitions in the xaml in VS2010.  How do I use Expression Blend to input RowDefinitions?

Answer (score 1):

Use Properties -> Layout -> Advanced Properties -> Row Definitions -> ... -> Add another item.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the xaml while in blend by flipping between Design view and XAML view using the icons in the top right of the main area.

You can also open the project in VS at the same time if there are features there you want to use.